# Common index page for 3 drupal sites

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I have 3 websites which were built on drupal, 3 are on different sub-domains each. Now i want to built a common index page for all 3 websites in which i want to show features of all 3 websites and to load faster. Also i want to move all the websites to sub-directory instead of sub-domain (Example: www.example.com/site1 instead of www.site1.example.com).

Is this a suggestible method? if done so should i work on.htaccess configuration too?

Please suggest me in this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with multi-site configuration. This is the most fascinating thing about Drupal. You can use single code base for multiple sites. Then you can configure them in the way you want. You can also define a common index page but its little bit tricky and may require some coding.